# Intercepting third party class using AspectJ

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to intercept spring's class using my implemented aspect.

My aspect looks like below:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class BatchExceptionInterceptor {

    @Around("execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(..))")
    public Object serviceMethodIntercept(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp)
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("I am here..");
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```

Also, I have used below tag in my Springs context file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

I am able to intercept my own classes this way. But not sure why SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate() is not being intercepted even program controller goes through this method. My aspect is being initialized properly. Any idea?

Comment: Because it isn't a spring bean. Spring uses proxies, it cannot create a proxy for a class that isn't a bean. Next to that it still wouldn't work as the call to `doTranslate` is an internal method call and due to the use of proxies you cannot intercept internal method calls only calls into the method i.e. the `translate` method. (But as mentioned first, as there is no bean of that type nothing will be intercepted).

Comment: Thank Deinum. What could be the other way to intercept SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(..)?

Comment: Why would you even need to intercept that?

Comment: The reason is SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator is not wrapping BatchUpdateException while throwing the exceptions. I want that even exceptions are wrapped, I must have BatchUpdateException reference somewhere in thrown exception so that I can print which row is actually failed in betch. Here is my question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740459/log-sql-parameter-value-if-exception-occured-on-performing-batch-update-using-sp

Comment: INstead of hacking with AOP just create your own `SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator` inject that into your `JdbcTemplate`... You are trying to use cannon to shoot a fly. You can just copy the existing one and modify/remove the lines you don't need.